# Como usar o seletor first-child para uma classe específica

Tags: css, seletores

Olá,
Tenho vários divs e alguns deles tem uma classe 'teste', gostaria que o seletor first-child destacasse apenas o primeiro DIV que tem a classe 'teste', porém, só funciona se a classe 'teste' esta no primeiro div. Pelo que entendi, o seletor pega o primeiro objeto do tipo e não a classe realmente. Alguém tem alguma idéia? Nesse exemplo abaixo, eu queria que o div com o "Teste 2" ficasse destacado pelo seletor (ele é o primeiro DIV que tem a classe teste).

```css
.teste:first-child{
 background-color:#F00;
 border:solid 4px #33CCCC; 
}
```

```html
<div>
  Teste 1
</div>
<div class="teste">
  Teste 2
</div>
<div class="teste">
  Teste 3
</div>
<div class="teste">
  Teste 4
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Não há seletores que façam isso infelizmente, os seletores atuais trabalham sobre a tag do elemento e não sobre a sua classe. O ideal aqui seria `:first-of-class` que não existe.

Há uma [ideia interessante](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8539107/2256325) que resolve o teu problema. Que é usando o [seletor `~`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors).

Nesse caso aplicas o estilo a todas as classes, e depois desfazes usando o seletor `.classe ~ .classe`, e desse modo apagas o estilo em todas menos a primeira... O seletor procura assim por um elemento com a classe x, precedido por outro com a classe x.

Seria assim:

```css
div.teste {
    background-color: #F00;
    border: solid 4px #33CCCC;
    color: #ccf;
}

.teste ~ .teste {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Teste 1
</div>
<div class="teste">
  Teste 2
</div>
<div class="teste">
  Teste 3
</div>
<div class="teste">
  Teste 4
</div>
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1fxcxgn4/

---

Como referi não há uma solução imediata com CSS, apesar de ser executável. Se quiseres usar JavaScript para evitar sobrecarregar o CSS com regras que podem ser complexas de remover podes usar assim:

```
var primeiroTeste = document.querySelector('.teste');
primeiroTeste.classList.add('classe');
```

onde terias no CSS:

```
.classe {
    background-color:#F00;
    border:solid 4px #33CCCC;   
}
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1fxcxgn4/1/